# How do you test xbox (via PC) input without an xbox on XNA Game Studio?

Tags: xna, input, xbox, controllers

Is it safe to just hookup a wired Xbox controller to my PC via USB? Do I need to buy a special PC Xbox controller? I've read conflicting reports. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an Xbox wired controller, or you can pick up the wireless receiver which plugs into your USB port and lets you use the wireless controllers with windows.

Here is a [link](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=Xbox+360+Wireless+Gaming+Receiver+for+Windows&cid=9984239196350938768&ei=2tyTTNTMEIm4iwTKuqGdCw&sa=title&ved=0CAcQ8wIwADgA#p) to the wireless receiver.

Comment: The only brick and mortar I found the wireless controller at was BestBuy.

Comment: The wireless controller adapters are not widely sold at all.Be aware that they fail easily too. At least they used to, not sure if they've fixed them in subsequent production batches.

Comment: I've found that the receiver is bundled with the "Wireless Xbox 360 controller for PC" which is much easier to find - and it will support up to 4 regular wirelessr Xbox 360 controllers...

Answer (score 2):

Any wired Xbox 360 will work when plugged in to a computers USB slot. Windows XP SP 3, Vista, and 7 will automatically install the drivers for you.

There are some wired controllers that specifically say "For PC" on them, but other than the packaging they are identically.

It is a standard USB device, and you will not hurt the controller, or a computer you plug it into.